# Is it possible to pass data to postgreSQL trigger?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, triggers

I need to log any changes made in some table by trigger which will insert older version of modified row to another table with some additional data like:

-which action was performed

-when this action was performed

-by who.

I have problem with last requirement. While performing SQL somewhere in java by JDBC. I need to somehow pass logged user id stored in variable to postgres table where all older versions of modified row will be stored.

Is it even possible?
It may be stupid question but I desperately try to avoid inserting data like that manually in java. Triggers done some work for me but not all I need.

Demonstrative code below (I've cut out some code for security reasons):

"notes" table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_database.notes
(
  pk serial NOT NULL,
  client_pk integer,
  description text,
  CONSTRAINT notes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (pk)
)
```

Table storing older versions of every row changed in "notes" table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_database_log.notes_log
(
  pk serial NOT NULL,
  note_pk integer,
  client_pk integer,
  description text,
  who_changed integer DEFAULT 0, -- how to fill in this field?
  action_date timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(), --when action was performed
  action character varying, --which action was performed
  CONSTRAINT notes_log_pkey PRIMARY KEY (pk)
)
```

Trigger for "notes" table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_or_update_note_trigger
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON database.notes
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_database.notes_new_row_log();
```

Procedure executed by trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_database.notes_new_row_log()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO my_database_log.notes_log(
            note_pk, client_pk, description, action)
    VALUES ( 
        NEW.pk, NEW.client_pk,  NEW.description, TG_OP);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION my_database.notes_new_row_log()
  OWNER TO database_owner;
```

Comment: While you can't pass an argument to a trigger, you can certainly store some value (user id) in some table and have the trigger retrieve it and then log it.

Comment: Call `set_config('myapp.userid', <user_id>)` from Java, then call `current_setting('myapp.userid')` to retrieve `<user_id>` in the trigger function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to @Nick Barnes hint in comments, there is a need to declare a variable in postgresql.conf file:

```
...

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CUSTOMIZED OPTIONS
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

custom_variable_classes = 'myapp'       # list of custom variable class names
myapp.user_id = 0
```

and call:

```
SET LOCAL customvar.user_id=<set_user_id_value_here>
```

before query that should be triggered.

To handle variable in trigger use:

```
current_setting('myapp.userid')
```

Comment: Note that the `postgresql.conf` entries are only necessary in Postgres 9.1 and earlier; nowadays you can just `SET` new variables on the fly.

Comment: Feel free to add your answer with more details if you want. I'll accept your answer and then delete mine because mine won't be necessary here.

Comment: No need, I think you pretty much covered it ;)

Comment: If your value is a variable, you need to swap `SET LOCAL ...` with `SELECT set_config('myapp.userid', _my_variable, TRUE)`.

Comment: Does this allow for multiple concurrent values of `myapp.userid` when set through config or local variable? 

This would be considering if multiple updates are happening to the same table around the same time.